# UI python file manager working on Linux but not windows

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, easygui

I am creating a file manager built on python and easygui but the script fails to open a file dialog box when the button <kbd>Convert .ply to .obj</kbd> is pressed.
I tried it earlier today and it worked, but I'm not sure I even changed anything.
The program freezes after the button is pressed.
I'm on windows 10.

The line that fails is:

```
# open a file box window
# when we want to select a file
def open_window():
    read=easygui.fileopenbox()
    return read
```

The process that calls this function is:

```
def ply_2_obj():
    #copy file then call ply2obj (imported)
    print("made it here")
    source1 = open_window()

    mb.showinfo('confirmation', "Converting .ply to .obj, this may take a minute")
    rv = os.system("python3 ply2obj.py %s" % source1)
    print("rv= " + rv)
    print("converted ply to obj")
```

However the program never makes it past `open_window()`.

The button is set up as:

```
Button(root, text = "Convert .ply to .obj file",
       command = ply_2_obj).grid(row = 95, column = 2)
```

Again, this worked an hour ago I'm not sure what is broken now.

Comment: Calling `os.system` to run a python file isn't advisable. Instead put all of the code inside `ply2obj.py` in a function then use `from ply2obj import function` and `function(source1)`

Comment: I tried reinstalling easygui and no change

Comment: Did you code `ply2obj.py`?

Comment: I did, the program never reaches this point however

Comment: I think the problem is that `python3 filename.py arg` works on Linux but for Windows the executable is `python` not `python3`. That is why I suggested that you use `import ply2obj` instead of `os.system`

Comment: Try using the path in `sys.executable` instead of `"python3"`. You may have to literally put double quotes around its value in the argument you pass to `os.system()` if the path has any space characters in it. i.e. `'"%s"' % (sys.executable,)`